# Inifinispan RemoteCache async get

Tags: asynchronous, infinispan

I'm trying to resolve the future result of `remoteCache.asyncGet`:

```
remoteCache.getAsync(key).attachListener(new FutureListener () {
        @Override
        public void futureDone(Future future) {
          Object res = future.get();
        }
});
```

The future that gets passed to futureDone listener is not completed, i.e. `future.isDone()` equals  false  and `future.get()` stacks forever.
In the logs I see that object was successfully fetched from infinispan cluster.

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks

Alexander

Comment: Could you share the logs? Especially those from client.
If you don't use FutureListener but call future.get() directly on the future, does is block forever as well?

Comment: No, get works as expected

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely a bug, even 2 in few lines of code:
 http://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-3868